# ) was unexpected at this time - Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
for /l %%a in (1 1 %highestDO1%) do (
    set /a valueT=%%a%
    ::echo T!valueT! M6 >> !fileName!
    set xAlt=X+0.000
for /l %%b in (1 1 !highestBD%%a%O1!) do (
    echo G52 X0Y0Z+0.000 >> !fileName!
    set /a maxImp=!numParts!-1
for /l %%c in (1 1 !maxImp!) do (
    echo M198P10%%a%%b% (%%c%^) >> !fileName!
    echo G52 !xInternal!!y!Z+0.000 >> !fileName!
    ::echo G68  R180. !xAlt!Y+0.000 >> !fileName!
)
    echo M198P10%%a%%b% (!numParts!^) >> !fileName!
    echo G52 X0Y0Z0 >> !fileName!
    echo. >> !fileName!
    if !xAlt!==X+0.000 (set xAlt=%x%) else (set xAlt=%x2%)
)
)
```

It fails at the first ) after %highestDO1% on the first line with a ") was unexpected at this time" error.  I have delayed expansion enabled.  I know it is this line because everything before executes as expected, and this exact code works without the %%c for loop in another version of the same code, plus I placed pauses before and after that line and only the first pause executes before the error shows.  I can add the preceding code if you feel it necessary, but it's a lot and working fine so I left it out for now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are adding an unnecessary percent character suffix to all of your for variables, `%%a%` should be `%%a`, `%%a%%b%` should be `%%a%%b` and `%%c%` should be `%%c`. In addition replace `::` with `REM` inside your for loops.

Comment: Remove the `::-style` comments and replace with `REM` comments. `:: is a broken label and can cause unexpected results as labels are not allowed in a `code block` (parenthesised series of commands).

Comment: Also replace `set /a valueT=%%a%` by `set valueT=%%a` as it is not necessary to convert the number string internally to an integer and back to a number string. `set /a maxImp=!numParts!-1` should be modified to `set /a maxImp=numParts-1` because in an __arithmetic expression__ envrionment variables can be referenced by just their names as help output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window explains in detail.

Comment: You can use `:: commented line` in a `if`/`esle`/`for` brace `( )` **but** should not put it as the **last line** in the brace `( )`.  If you need, just like **Magoo** said, use `REM` instead of `::` .  What's more, suggest you use `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`  or `SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` at top of your script and use `!varName!` instead of  `%varName%` to reference a variable.